# Как задать 100% width от родителя родителя

Tags: html, css

Имею следующий DOM:

```css
.rightBlock {
  background: #ececec;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  left: 265px;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 414px;
  left: 265px;
}

.messagesBlock {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 93%;
  width: 100%;
}

div .userInfoTopPanel {
  width: 100%;
  height: 45px;
  background: white;
  z-index: 15;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="rightBlock">
  <div class="messagesBlock">
    <div class="userInfoTopPanel"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

В итоге, userInfoTopPanel имеет ширину окна браузера, мне же нужно, чтобы у него была ширина от messagesBlock

Answer (score 1):

```css
html,body{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  }

.rightBlock {
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  left: 265px;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 414px;
  
  left: 265px;
}

.messagesBlock {
  background: blue;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 93%;
  width: 100%;
}

div .userInfoTopPanel {
  width: 100%;
  height: 45px;
  background: green;
  z-index: 15;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="rightBlock">
  <div class="messagesBlock">
    <div class="userInfoTopPanel"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Жаль, но на моем варианте это не работает.

Я изменил так только html

Answer (score 1):

Ты использовал свойство `position: fixed;`, которое накладывает ряд ограничений и установка относительных размеров как раз одно из них.

Поэтому ты можешь

1) установить абсолютные размеры (например, в пикселях)

2) отслеживать изменение размеров родительского окна и через javascript устанавливать размеры дочернему...динамически

3) обрати внимание на свойство `position: stycky;`

https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_position_sticky

Смотри что произошло - ты указал, что .userInfoTopPanel должен быть зафиксирован относительно основного окна, поэтому и размеры теперь устанавливаются относительно основного окна, а не относительно родительского элемента.

**P.S.**

если ты укажешь более точно что именно ты хотел бы получить, то и решение можно будет указать более точно